# Accept different html template data as options for reactjs component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, composition

In reactjs how do i render a component with template html data ?

```
class Options extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const othList = [];

        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((t) => {
            othList.push(t);
        });

        return othList;
    }
}
```

How do i pass html data and use the supplied html as template ?

```
<Options><div></div></Options>
```

So the above will render 5 divs mainly 1 etc..
or 
`<Options><td></td></Options>` will render 5 td's

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Dangerously set inner html

If you have html as a string you can use this method in react to set it in the component.

From the docs

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}} />;
}
```

In your code (assuming othList is an array of html templates)

```
class Options extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const othList = [];

        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((t) => {
            othList.push(t);
        });

        let activeTemplateIndex = 0;

        return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: othList[activeTemplateIndex]}} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the html passed as props.children as html template and return data bounded to the html ? So if i pass <Options><td></td></Options> i want the Options component to render 5 td's ?